# Google Maps not being displayed, JavaScript IntelXDK

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, intel-xdk

I am using Intel XDK to try and get the google maps displayed on the screen at the location set in Intel XDK. However, I am having issues with actually displaying the map on the screen, after spending many hours researching trying to figure out why it isn't working I have hit a brick wall and I have no idea how to proceed from here.

So any help will be greatly appreciated to point me in the right direction, thanks in advance.

**Index.html class**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <!--
  * Please see the included README.md file for license terms and conditions.
  -->

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jqm/jquery.mobile-min.css">
        <title>Blank App Designer Cordova Web App Project Template</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">


        <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1"> -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=2"> -->

        <style>
 100% ; }          @viewport { width: 100vw ; min-zoom: 100% zoom: 100% ; }
                @-ms-viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; min-zoom: 100% ; }                   @viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; min-zoom: 100% ; }

        </style>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index_main.less.css" class="main-less">

        <!-- <script src="lib/mc/hammer.js"></script> -->
        <!-- <script src="lib/ft/fastclick.js"></script> -->

        <script src="cordova.js" id="xdkJScordova_"></script>

        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
       <!-- <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;signed_in=true"></script>-->
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyApiKey&amp;callback=initMap"></script>

        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Maps.js"></script>

        <script type="application/javascript" src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="jqm/jquery.mobile-min.js" data-ver="0"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="js/index_user_scripts.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="sidebar/js/hammer.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="sidebar/js/jquery.hammer.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="sidebar/js/swipe-hammer.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="sidebar/js/sidebar.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="xdk/ad/jqm_subpage.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body id="afui" class="v2" onload="navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError)">

        <!-- IMPORTANT: Do not include a weinre script tag as part of your release builds! -->
        <!-- Place your remote debugging (weinre) script URL from the Test tab here, if it does not work above -->
        <!-- <script src="http://debug-software.intel.com/target/target-script-min.js#insertabiglongfunkynumberfromthexdkstesttab"></script> -->
        <div class="upage vertical-col left" id="mainpage" data-role="page"><a class="widget uib_w_2 d-margins" data-uib="jquery_mobile/button" data-ver="0" data-role="button" id="maps" href="#Maps" data-transition="fade">Maps</a>

            <a class="widget uib_w_3 d-margins" data-uib="jquery_mobile/button" data-ver="0" data-role="button" id="gps">GPS</a>
        </div>

        <div class="upage" id="Maps" data-role="page" >
            <div class="upage-outer" >

                <div class="upage-content ac0 content-area vertical-col left" id="page_70_37"><a class="widget uib_w_4 d-margins" data-uib="jquery_mobile/button" data-ver="0" data-role="button">Button</a>

                <div id="map" style="height: 500px; width: 300px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">    


                </div>
                <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="container-group inner-element uib_w_6" data-uib="jquery_mobile/footer" data-ver="0">
                    <h1>footer</h1>
                    <div class="widget-container wrapping-col single-centered"></div>
                    <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col left"></div>
                    <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col right"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer-element uib_w_5 uib_crossbar botbar fixed bar-bg thumb-bg bar-gutter" data-uib="layout/bottom_crossbar" data-ver="1" data-anim="{'style':'overlap', 'v':400, 'side':'bottom', 'dur':500}">
                <div class="sidebar-content content-area vertical-col">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

**App.js**

```
  var latitude;
    var longitude;
    var onSuccess = function(position) {
    alert(

    latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    longitude = position.coords.longitude;
};

function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

var locationOptions = {
 maximumAge: 10000,
 timeout: 6000,
 enableHighAccuracy: true
};
```

**Maps.js**

```
function initMap() {
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
    zoom: 16,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude)//{latitude, longitude}

  });
  //var marker = new google.maps.marker({position: LatLng, map:map});

  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('right-panel'));

/*      // stops the text directions when un commented

  var control = document.getElementById('floating-panel');
  control.style.display = 'block';
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(control);
*/ 

  var onChangeHandler = function() {
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
  };
  document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
  document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
  var start = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude)//{latitude, longitude};
  var end = '10 Downing Street, Downing Street, London';
  directionsService.route({
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

**Index_User_Scripts**

```
   /*jshint browser:true */
/*global $ */(function()
{
 "use strict";
 /*
   hook up event handlers 
 */
 function register_event_handlers()
 {


     /* button  Button */
    $(document).on("click", ".uib_w_1", function(evt)
    {
        /* your code goes here */ 
    });

        /* button  #maps */
    $(document).on("click", "#maps", function(evt)
    {
         /*global activate_page */
         activate_page("#Maps"); 
         initMap();
         //calculateAndDisplayRoute();
    });

        /* button  #gps */
    $(document).on("click", "#gps", function(evt)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    });

    }
 document.addEventListener("app.Ready", register_event_handlers, false);
})();
```

Comment: Did you tried to set the map height in your css? This was a problem that i had often.

Comment: HI Kabaehr, 

I am setting the style for the map here  <div id="map" style="height: 500px; width: 300px; margin: 0; padding: 0;"> in the index.html class.

Comment: If you're having no problems in your code but no map is being displayed, it could be that you did not enable Google Maps API on your Google Developer Console.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have permission to use Google API. I used the Google Maps widget and tried with two locations, Statue of Liberty and Taj Mahal. I was able to make it work in emulator as well as on the Intel XDK Preview apps on my phones. Details are in this post:
http://hodentekmobile.blogspot.com/2016/07/intel-xdk-controls-6-using-google-map.html
Here are the settings I used for the widget:
[image: Settings: Google Map widget]